# dictionary key value concatenation

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm attempting to concatenate (which I believe is the best way to do things here) my key/value pairs in my dict. What I would like to do is append these key/values to a list and then use join() to make that one large string. I would prefer this to work as a function and for any dict that is passed. Here is an example dict,

```
dictyy = {'first': 'one', 2: 'two', 'something': 'somethingValue',
      'somethingelse': 'somethingElseValue', 'last': 'lastvalue'}
```

I really only care that the concatenated string has the 'first' and 'last' keys in their respective [0] and [-1] positions. I know I will always have those two keys so I should be able to place them in the string like this.

`stringyy = 'python first' + dictyy['first'] + '{} {} {} {}' + 'last' + dictyy['last']'.format(key1, dictyy['key1'], key2, dictyy['key2'])`

The other values can be in any order. What's tricky here is that I could receive anywhere from 1-4 of those 'middle' key/values in `dictty` and I'm not sure how to account for this varying number. I know what the keys would be but I don't always have to receive certain keys so if I have a predefined string that I want to format and reference a specific value for a key that wasn't passed along, then I'll receive a `KeyError`.

Other than conditionals, is there any way to prepare for this uncertainty of what I'll receive and is there any way to directly reference a key in a dict? Something that could work like this may help:

```
def get_keys(dictyy):
    for key in dictyy.keys() != 'first or 'last'
        print key
```

Comment: The other keys would be `[key for key in dictyy if key not in ('first', 'last')]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will try that out. is that a typo in your comment too? 'In' instead of 'for key n dictyy' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.pop` to extract values for your first and last keys, while removing those keys from your dictionary.

You can then use `itertools.chain` with `str.join` to retrieve all key-value pairs as a single string. Note that dictionaries are considered unordered (unless you are using Python 3.7+), you should not expect these key-value pairs to be output in any particular order.

Finally, f-strings (Python 3.6+) are an efficient method of combining your variables.

Here's a demo:

```
from itertools import chain

first_key = 'first'
last_key = 'last'

first_val = dictyy.pop(first_key)
last_val = dictyy.pop(last_key)
middles = ' '.join(map(str, chain.from_iterable(dictyy.items())))

res = f'{first_key} {first_val} {middles} {last_key} {last_val}'

print(res)

'first one 2 two something somethingValue somethingelse somethingElseValue last lastvalue'
```

Answer (score 1):

This guarantees that the elements are placed in the exact order as you want them.

```
my_dict = {
            'first': 'one', 2: 'two', 'something': 'somethingValue',
            'somethingelse': 'somethingElseValue', 'last': 'lastvalue'
        }

rows_list=list(my_dict.keys())
values_list=list(my_dict.values())

stringyy = ''
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    stringyy = stringyy + str(k) + ':' + str(v) + ' '

print(stringyy)
```

Output: 
`first:one 2:two something:somethingValue somethingelse:somethingElseValue last:lastvalue`
Check methods that dictionaries can use, like `items()` `keys()` and `values()`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: What's the point of "rows_list=list(my_dict.keys())
values_list=list(my_dict.values())" if you don't use those variables?